# Has the Biden administration communicated a plan for overcoming US division?

Tags: united-states, policy, democratic-party, joe-biden

For now, civil society in the US looks [divided](https://www.ap.org/explore/divided-america/), and that is a problem.

Has the incoming Biden administration or the Democratic party expressed any specific policies or plans for the purpose of addressing this issue?

Comment: I can't see how this is answerable, at least until Biden announces something that he is going to do in this area.

Comment: Odd to close a question about the biggest challenge the US is facing.  Maybe rephrasing it to something like *Has Biden communicated a plan...* would improve it.  As to actual steps in that direction, besides wowing with competence, as per John Bode's answer, conciliatory gestures are possible, such as:  appoint moderate Reps where appropriate, not appointing too-far-left Dems and above all, expressly disavowing Supreme Court packing.

Comment: I don't see it as inherently problematic.  Its no problem that people disagree with each other. In fact that's rather normal.  More problematic would be if everybody agreed, there was one party that everybody supported (at least everybody who mattered)

Comment: It's not a problem government can solve.  As a people, we have to choose to be less sensitive, more forgiving, less hostile, and more gentle.  The media is in a much better position to help than the government is. Unfortunately, these days, the media is more antagonistic that anything.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the Democratic Party Platform for the 2020 elections contains a section entitled ["Healing the Soul of America"](https://democrats.org/where-we-stand/party-platform/healing-the-soul-of-america/), which begins:

> Democrats believe in bringing the American people together, not
> stoking division and distrust. President Trump has denigrated
> virtually every segment of American society—and in so doing, he has
> insulted the very idea of America itself. Healing the soul of America
> means facing up to the deepest inequities in our society, from
> structural racism to misogyny to discrimination against people with
> disabilities, and enacting ambitious measures to fix them.

The full section is far too long to reproduce here, but it includes commitments to "use federal law enforcement tools and resources to address domestic terrorism", as well as a promise to "ensure federal data collection and analysis is adequately funded and designed to allow for disaggregation by race and ethnicity, among other important factors, to better design policies to address the needs of the most vulnerable communities and make informed policy choices".

This section seems to cover the majority of the Democratic Party position on the race and gender points from the link in the question, but on the issue of the economy, the section entitled ["Building a Stronger, Fairer Economy"](https://democrats.org/where-we-stand/party-platform/building-a-stronger-fairer-economy/) seems more relevant, focusing on the issues of intergenerational mobility as well as the "persistent, pernicious racial wealth gap". This section contains promises such as a raise in the federal minimum wage, as well as tax-credits for first-time homebuyers as part of their goal to "address long-standing economic and racial inequities in our housing markets".

Comment: A fair answer from Biden/Democratic perspective, but I suspect many Republicans will see many if not all those measures working against their ideals. Mkay maybe I'm too pessimistic, but e.g. half of Republicans didn't dig affirmative action https://www.npr.org/2018/11/01/658960740/how-americans-feel-about-affirmative-action-in-higher-education

Comment: @Fizz I'm sure, but the question asks for the Democratic plan :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I upvoted. Btw, the Republicans seems about just as split on whether the US has too much or "just the right amount" of economic inequality https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2020/01/09/views-of-economic-inequality/

Comment: Finally I'm not sure if those measures can help with the perception/culture division which is incredibly [stark](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2020/10/09/voters-feelings-about-the-election-and-possible-outcomes/#many-see-lasting-harm-if-the-other-partys-candidate-wins-in-november), except maybe in the long run.

Comment: @Fizz well, yes, because the entire Republican strategy has been to provoke division and benefit from it. It's a "prisoner's dilemma" situation where "defect" is working for them.

Comment: Let's not do the endless argument about whether a party's plan will work or not. The question asked if there is a plan, and this answer tells us what it is.

Answer (score 5):

There’s nothing the Biden administration or the Democratic Party *can* do except govern as effectively as possible, which is going to be difficult at best because of bad actors in Congress and the news media.

We’re seeing the end result of decades’ worth of grievance and misinformation pushed by talk radio, certain cable news networks, and other alternate news sources.  With the democratization of media made possible by the Internet, there’s no effective gatekeeping to stop disinformation and propaganda from being disseminated.

The downside of a free press is that we have no good way of stopping anyone from just making stuff up and publishing it as news, at least not without running afoul of the 1st Amendment and a couple of centuries of case law.

The other problem is that we citizens treat politics as a reality show and elect performative jackasses who have no ability or desire to actually govern.

This isn’t a top-down problem with a top-down solution.  In a democracy, you get the government you deserve.

Comment: This is just opinion. Plenty of people have plans that could help reunite the country.

Comment: @DJClayworth:  You can’t make people like each other or like you.  You can try to appeal to their better nature, but if they don’t have one it’s kind of a waste of time,

Comment: No, you can't. But you can do things that make it easier for people to accept each other, or work together cooperatively despite their differences, or focus on the things that unite them, or make it unacceptable to openly promote hatred against each other, or many other things that help overcome division. And sometimes people do actually change their minds and like each other. Do you consider Japanese people your enemy? Your grandfather probably did.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. OP isn't asking whether Biden's plan to heal the nation's divide will actually *work*, he's just asking whether such a plan *exists*.